# Does an English translation of "Logica ‘ingredientibus’" by Peter Abelard exist?

Tags: logic, theology

Pretty much the title, first time I'm having trouble finding anything.

Comment: You may have a look at Peter King's site; also Paul Vincent Spade's site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only parts, and they are not easy to get. Here is a useful website, [Abelard's Philosophical Works: Editions, Translations, Selected Texts](https://www.historyoflogic.com/biblio/abelard-editions.htm) that contains detailed bibliography of Abelard's works and their modern translations. In full, Logica 'Ingredientibus' was translated into German and Italian several times, but not into English. The most popular part of it, Glosses on Porphyry, was translated into English, and the translations appears in the following volumes:

1) Philosophy in the Middle Ages. The Christian, Islamic and Jewish Traditions, edited by Hyman and Walsh, Indianapolis: Hackett, 1973.

2) Five Texts on the Mediaeval Problem of Universals: Porphyry, Boethius, Abelard, Duns Scotus, Ockham, edited by Spade, Indianapolis: Hackett, 1994.

3) Readings in Medieval Philosophy, edited by Schoedinger, New York: Oxford University Press, 1996.

Peter King's doctoral dissertation, in three volumes, defended in Princeton in 1982 has the longest excerpts in English, from parts I and III, translated from Geyser's German 1933 translation. They appear in Appendix to volume 2. The dissertation is available from ProQuest Dissertation Express.